# Spring + gradle compiles only one time then thows ClassNotFoundException on main class

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, gradle

I'm trying to learn Spring. I followed a tutorial with Java and Maven, and everything worked perfectly, However, I wanted to use Kotlin instead of Java, so I generated a new project by following [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin/).

The first time I launched the app, I had no problems, but when I relaunched it, I received this exception:

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.blog.BlogApplication
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.blog.BlogApplication

This error occurs with Java and Kotlin, and my class exists and is correctly compiled, so the only one problem comes from Gradle.

I found 2 solutions to fix this error:

1. Removing directory ".gradle/6.8.3"
2. Using an older version of gradle (5.6.4 instead of 6.8.3)

Of course, these are not fully satisfying and I'd like to use the latest version.

Does anyone have an idea? Is it simply impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. This is just not possible as said in this issue : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/24225